# Aligning text links underneath each other

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to align text links underneath each other but for some reason some of the links doesn't go underneath each other.

This is how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gonA.jpg.

This is what I want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH0Ap.jpg

Here is the code so far:

HTML:

```
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="bottom-column">
        <div class="bottom-header">STREETZ</div>
        <a class"bottom-link" href="#Home">Home</a>
        <a class"bottom-link" href="#About">About us</a>
        <a class"bottom-link" href="#Sitemap">Sitemap</a>
        <a class"bottom-link" href="#Blog">Blog</a>
        <a class"bottom-link" href="#Blog">Privacy Policy</a>
        <a class"bottom-link" href="#Blog">Terms of Service</a>

      </div>

      <div class="bottom-column">
        <div class="bottom-header">SUPPORT</div>
        <a class"bottom-link" href="#Home">FAQ</a>
        <a class"bottom-link" href="#About">Contact us</a>
        <a class"bottom-link" href="#Sitemap">Shipping</a>
        <a class"bottom-link" href="#Blog">Returns</a>
      </div>   
    </footer>
```

CSS:

```
     .footer {
      position: relative;
      width: 1024px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #f5f5f5;
      margin: 0 auto;
      top: 1255px;
      border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    }

    .bottom-header {
      font-size: 14px;
      line-height: 20px;
      position: relative;
      color: #333;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .bottom-column {
      float:left;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 15px;
      width: 105px;
      height: 160px;
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .bottom-column a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #6a6a6a;
      float: left;
      left: 50px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
```

Comment: just put a <br /> after each link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
.bottom-column a {
    display: block; //To force the text links to stack on top of one another
}
```

And remove the `float:left` from `.bottom-column a {...}`.
The `float` is causing the links to be lined up against each other.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shiazure/gvHN8/1/).

Comment: @Nohman Corrected it. Accidentally skimmed over the `float` the first time.

Comment: @Nohman You're welcome. :) But why haven't you marked it as the answer if it worked?

Comment: I have to wait 2 minutes, that's why :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 'clear: both;' to .bottom-column a

```
.bottom-column a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6a6a6a;
  float: left;
  left: 50px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  clear: both;
}
```